# ensemble averaging

Tags: plotting

Here`phix`is $\phi_{xx}$ a coherence matrix and the angle brackets denote ensemble averaging. $E_x$ is the x component of the electric field.

$$\phi_{xx}=\langle E_x^* E_x \rangle$$

with the following angles and functions

```
a:= 45 Pi/180;
phi:= 0; 

b[n_, v_, t_, a_, u_]:= 
BesselJ[n, v Sin@t/Sin@a] Exp[
I u Cos@t/Sin@a^2];

r[n_, t_]:= {(1 + Cos@t), 
 Sin@t, (1 - Cos@t)}[[n + 1]] Sqrt@
Cos@t Sin@t;

i[n_, u_, v_, a_]:= 
i[n, u, v, a] = 
NIntegrate[
r[n, t] b[n, v, t, a, u], {t, 
 0,a}];
```

The electric field and $\phi_{xx}$

```
e[u_, v_]:= -I k/
2 (i[0, u, v, a] + i[2, u, v, a] Cos[2 phi]);

phix:= Mean[Conjugate[e[u, v]] e[u, v]];

Plot[phix, {v, 0, 7.01}]
```

`phix` is here only dependend on v. For this case I set `u=0`. What else than `Mean` can be used to do the averaging? (`Mean` does not work here because I think the field can not just randomly averaged.) Thanks!

Comment: What are `u` and `v`?  Are they angles?  `e` is a function of `u` and `v`, but when you plot `phix` it is only a function of `v` - so you are going to have to average over the variable `u`.  Usually this would mean an integral over the distribution, whatever that may be

Comment: `u` and `v` are the variables. I edited my post. If I assume u to be `0` only for `phix`, would it make it more handable now?

Comment: If you assume `u` to be zero, then in what way are you taking the ensemble average?

Comment: I could set `v := Sqrt[(vx)^2 + (vy)^2]` like this.